# Paragraph starting positioning itext

Tags: itext

I am using **IText** library. I am using **Paragraph** in it cause the text is running and may be larger then one page. My problem is that I have to give paragraph  starting positioning and I am unable to see any method regarding positioning it. Any help?
Something like that
[image]

page 2 is new page.... And this is  whole one paragraph. I have starting coordinate of paragraph.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried yet (some code preferred), what that code produced, and what exactly you want instead.

Comment: My question is basically using paragraph with ABSOLUTE POSITION. But as far as I saw I cant add paragraph to a PdfPtable or ColumnText Cause Paragraph may be larger than one page. If I will add it, it will cut other remaining text and will not go to other page.

Comment: The question isn't clear. What do you want to happen with the Paragraph if it doesn't fit the page? Did you read chapter 3 of the book? Do you understand the ColumnText mechanism?

Comment: @MGDroid If i understand you correctly, you want to use the normal iText automatic layout mechanism but at the same time want to move the current insertion position to an absolute position of your choice. If that is the case I'm afraid that that functionality is not present there yet.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I think from image I am a little bit clear. You have developed this helpful library. So is there any possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: OK, so the paragraph can continue on the next page. That's standard use of ColumnText.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie How can I achieve that Sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment section, you need `ColumnText` to achieve what you want. See for instance the [MovieColumns1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=64) example. You add text to a `ColumnText` instance with the `addText()` method. Then you set some parameters, such as the coordinates of the rectangle defining the absolute positions. This is done with the `setSimpleColumn()` method. To draw the text, you invoke the `go()` method. If the text didn't fit in the rectangle, `ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)` will return true, in which case, you trigger `newPage()`, define a new rectangle, change the Y position, and `go()` again as long as the column contains content.

All of this is explained in the documentation of which I'm the author. Reading the documentation saves time: your time as well as the time of the people on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching for the first occurrence of a line break or carriage return, ie: Chr(13) and Chr(20).

Comment: a coding example will be very helpful.